# Files changing name when uploading

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an admin page bootstrap that will upload files (jpg,gif,pdf,docx) to my database. The problem is everytime i upload a file, the file name is changing to another name. For example: I upload a jpg named 1.jpg and when it goes to my upload folder it is renamed as 6049.jpg

My php insert file:

```
   <?php

function upload_image()
{
    if(isset($_FILES["user_image"]))
    {
        $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['user_image']['name']);
        $new_name = rand() . '.' . $extension[1];
        $destination = './upload/' . $new_name;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        return $new_name;
    }
}

function get_image_name($user_id)
{
    include('db3.php');
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT image FROM users1 WHERE id = '$user_id'");
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        return $row["image"];
    }
}

function get_total_all_records()
{
    include('db3.php');
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users1");
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    return $statement->rowCount();
}

?>
```

Comment: That's what your code is doing. `$new_name = rand() . '.' . $extension[1];` -> generate random number + file extension. `$destination = './upload/' . $new_name;` -> append some path to the new name. `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $destination);` -> upload file with new name (randomized number + extension).

Comment: @JayDoe comment on this line `$new_name = rand() . '.' . $extension[1];` becoz `The rand() function generates a random integer.`

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from the code:

```
$new_name = rand() . '.' . $extension[1];
```

Line 5 or 7

And if you want the original name:

```
$new_name = $extension[0] . '.' . $extension[1];
```

Comment: You might want to rethink this answer for a couple of reasons: removing the line where you set value to a variable will cause undefined notices when later using it. Besides, why explode if you are just going to reassemble the values again?

Comment: Idk, he might need to store the extension on the database

Comment: They don't even know what their (supposedly) own code does xD

Comment: This works but the why is that when the file name is long is doesnt save properly and doesnt have extension?

Comment: @FirstOne i try to change explode to pathinfo and it doesnt upload anymore, what is the correct function to show the full name of file?

Comment: Just use this on $new_name  = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];

And try to understand the code you copied